# Closing Browser not work on Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome using Flex 4.6

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I am using Flash Builder 4.6, Creating Flex Application. I am trying to close browser using flex 4.6 code.This is work on Internet Explore but not work in Mozilla Firefox or Google Chrome. My code is here

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"     
        xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"      
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

<fx:Script> 
    <![CDATA[
protected function btnClose_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:window.close()"); 
            navigateToURL(url,"_self");             
        }

    ]]> 
</fx:Script> 
<s:Button id="btnClose" x="44" y="47" label="Close Browser" click="btnClose_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

Comment: This is more of a JavaScript question than a Flex one. It looks like IE is the only one to assign the current window to the `window` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ive found that browsers are inconsistent in interpreting the second parameter of navigateToURL.

If your swf is not in an html frame, you can use "_top" instead of "_self" (which does work across browsers):

```
navigateToURL(url,"_top");
```

Or just leave out the second parameter completely (as the default is the same as targetting "_self"):

```
navigateToURL(url);
```

Comment: thanks for my reply but my problem is not solved. Both of your suggestion is not working on google chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not allowed in most browsers, and for good reasons. You would have to exploit bugs or hacks to achieve it...

A popular one was to refresh and close it in javascript:

window.open('', '_self', ''); 
window.close();

My advice would be, dont do it.